# List<T> to implement IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

I'm trying to create a mock for my `IRepository` interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : ICollection<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
}
```

With this implementation:

```
public class RepositoryFake<T> : List<T>, IRepository<T>
{
    public Expression Expression
    {
        get
        {
            return this.AsQueryable().Expression;
        }
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.AsQueryable().ElementType;
        }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            return this.AsQueryable().Provider;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use it, I'm getting `StackOverflow` exception. How to implement this interface correctly to be able to use just a `List` as a repository?

Usage is very simple

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    RepositoryFake<User> users = new RepositoryFake<User>();
    users.Add(new User());

    List<User> list = (from user in users 
                 where user.Id == "5"
                 select user).ToList();

    Assert.That(list, Is.Empty);
}
```

Here is screenshot of exception:

[image: Exception]

Comment: "But when I use it" -- show us the code?  Show us the stack trace?

Comment: What are you trying to do? My best guess is you are hoping for some magic. The behavior is completely expected.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that if you perform `AsQueryable` it checks if the object already implements `IQueryable` and if yes returns it.

Use `new EnumerableQuery<T>(this)` instead of `AsQueryable` which doesn't perform this check.

---

Workaround for .net 3.5:

```
return ((IEnumerable<T>)this).Select(x=>x).AsQueryable()
```

First casts to `IEnumerable<T>` so the chosen `Select` method will be `Enumerable.Select` not `Queryable.Select`. The identity select will then return a new object that does not implement `IQueryable<T>`, so the check if it's implemented in `AsQueryable` fails.

Comment: The constructor taking an `IEnumerable<T>` is public. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190806.aspx At least on .net 4

Comment: You included both the cast to `IEnumerable<T>` and the `Select`?

Comment: Second option did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Seems very weird to me. In my particular case this caused our server to use 100% CPU, debugging revealed that all db rows were instantiated as objects in memory

Comment: @dksh This is designed to reuse `IQueryable` code on an `IEnumerable`, for example for testing. It's not designed to query a SQL database since anything `IEnumerable` based, even when converted to an `IQueryable` needs to iterate over everything instead of translating the query to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `base.AsQueryable()` instead of `this.AsQueryable()`.

Comment: Base class doesn't have such an extension

Comment: Wouldn't help anyways since the check if `IQueryable<T>` is already implemented uses the runtime type. This is no virtual method.